# ~Portrait and ~Landscape not work when use imageNamed in iOS7?

Tags: ios, ios7

I develop a universal app and setBackgroundImage for a button

```
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"keyImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I make 8 image for each button like this

```
keyImage~Landscape@2x~ipad.png
keyImage~Landscape~ipad.png     
keyImage~Portrait@2x~ipad.png
keyImage~Portrait~ipad.png

keyImage~Landscape@2x~iphone.png
keyImage~Landscape~iphone.png           
keyImage~Portrait@2x~iphone.png
keyImage~Portrait~iphone.png
```

The image display OK in iOS6 simulator(auto select Portrait or Landscape for non-Rentina and Rentina)

But this way (imageNamed:@"keyImage") not work in iOS7 simulator(no image display).

**How to use image named conversion for universal app in iOS7?**

I try with image asset but it have no setting for orientation.

Please help!Thanks!

Comment: I think the `~landscape`, `~portrait` identifiers are available only for launch images not for all resources. Also the identifiers are not capitalise, and be careful the simulator is not key sensitive while the device is. Not sure about the latest simulators.

Comment: Thanks! maybe that! But this way work in iOS6.